# Windows 8: Certificate install through website fails

Tags: vpn, ssl-certificate, internet-explorer, windows-8

I've installed Windows 8 Enterprise replacing Windows 7 Professional. Windows 8 comes with Internet Explorer 10. The company policy requires logging into a site through IE and then requesting for a VPN certificate and finally installing that VPN certificate all from within IE. The problem is that IE 10 is not opening the request page and throws a "The page can't be displayed" error. I can open the page in Chrome by clicking "Proceed Anyway" on the "Site certificate is invalid" warning but then it won't go further. The site is designed to run on IE and I believe it uses some certificate access COM dlls internally (certadm.dll). I can't install any other version of IE because Win 8 do not support it. The only option I am left with is to UNINSTALL Windows 8 but I want to make sure there's no solution before I do that.
Any Ideas? Some way to debug the problem in IE?

Comment: Are you talking about IE10 in Metro or Desktop ? The two aren't doing the same thing (and the former simply won't run ActiveX controls)

Comment: Its IE Desktop.

Comment: What VPN software are you using ? I would strongly suggest you seek help with your network admins regarding this kind of issue. It is possible that the software simply doesn't support IE10

Comment: Its the CISCO VPN. The network guys are saying that this won't work in IE 10 but I want to make sure before I uninstall Win 8.

Answer (score 2):

According to various reports from Fortune and InformationWeek, many enterprise users have experienced compatibility issues with their new copies of [Windows 8](http://www.dell.com/us/p/d/campaigns/windows-8-consumer) Enterprise. Many of these issues involve older programs that were primarily designed to work with Windows XP and Windows 7. These issues can sometimes extend to programs intended to work with Internet Explorer. Unfortunately, the VPN certificate you’re using may not be compatible with IE 10. The best solution is to consult your network administrators about this issue. If your network admins aren’t able to resolve the issue, you may have to uninstall Windows 8.

http://www.dell.com/us/p/d/campaigns/windows-8-consumer